# How to add(sum) the column data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

```
ID  pcID    contractor  approver    claimed
-------------------------------------------
1   1       one          1000         900
2   1       two           200         100
3   1       three        1000        1000
4   1       six           100          11
5   2       six           100          22
6   3       six           120           1
7   4       three         102          10
```

From the above table I need to sum the approver amount and claimed amount based on the contractor. Like the below given table. All has been done by using the stored procedure.

```
ID  pcID    contractor  approver    claimed  TotalApprover   TotalClaimed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1       one          1000         900     1000               900
2   1       two           200         100      200               100
3   1       three        1000        1000     1000              1000
4   1       six           100          11      100                11
5   2       six           100          22      200                33
6   3       six           120           1      320                34
7   4       three         102          10     1120              1001
```

Like the above table I need an output adding(sum) in ascending order based on contractor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You want cumulative sums:

```
select t.*,
       sum(approver) over (partition by contractor order by claimid) as totalapprover,
       sum(claim) over (partition by contractor order by claimid) as totalclaim
from t;
```

This is just accumulated the corresponding values by the dimensions you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It works properly man.... if it is possible Can you please explain that sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function

```
select t.*,
  sum(approver) over( partition by contractor order by ID) TotalApprover,
  sum(claimed) over( partition by contractor order by ID) TotalClaimed,
from table1 t
```